# Why are the net forces in this FBD $mg\sin \theta$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, free-body-diagram

Question:

[image]

[image]

It says the sum of the net forces is $mg\sin\theta$. I have tried drawing the angle in two ways:

[image]

and

[image]

both cases i get that net forces $=mg\sin\theta$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One thing you do wrong is not showing what the question is,  to start with. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Your question asks *Why is the net force  $mg\sin\theta$?* You state that in both cases you get the net force to be  $mg\sin\theta$. So why do you think you are doing something wrong?